# What is SSISDB in Denali

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In Sql Denali, so far the SSIS is concern we have something as SSISDB.It is a rather new stuff. I searched in the net to get good info on the same but no proper luck. could anyone please explain me in detail as what it is.
Any link or reference will also do.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [SSIS Junkie Denali blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/11/10/introduction-to-ssis-projects-in-denali.aspx)